# Maven Multi-Module plus Extrenal Tests plus JaCoCo plus Sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco

On our company we have the several modules on project and each module has several unit tests, but we have system tests that based on classes and not modules. Our system tests use several classes of each module (not all). We cannot calculate intergration coverage and unit coverage of this tests. We want to merge results of system tests to calculate the coverage of all probuct.

Anyone have any idea how we can do this? Anyone can provide any tutorial with examples?

Comment: Check out this article: http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample application that reproduces this case here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco

This should help you.